# Twig and atomic pattern — Clean twig rendering

Tags: symfony, twig, frontend, twig-extension

I'm trying to follow the [atomic design pattern](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/) with twig.

When rendering a simple atom, I need to do something like:

```
{% include '@MyBundle/Resources/views/atoms/button/button.html.twig' with { href: '/section1', text: 'Example text' } only %}
```

This approach starts getting messy when the atom or component has more variables, or the directory structure is a bit more complex.

I'd be awesome to be able to do something like:

```
{% button('/section1','Example text') %}
```

I know that this can be achieved with a twig function, but I'm worried this pattern can get tricky with a larger code base.

Any experience around this? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `macro` structure. Read documentation: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

```
{% macro button(href, text) %}
    {% here you can place your template %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then you will need only import your twig file with `macro` once. After that you can use construction like `{% button('/section1','Example text') %}`.

Comment: Thanks! It's a great starting point, and much easier and cleaner than using functions.